DNS Client Events（ID=1014）発生以降、FTPが延々失敗します
以下のような現象があって、原因追及と対策について検討しています。
お知恵を拝借できればと、質問させていただきます。
環境
OS : Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 10.0.17763
XYZ : C# GUIアプリケーション（Visusal Studio 2019/.NET Framework 4.7.2）
現象
ある装置の状態を1分毎に監視して、その結果をウェブサーバーにFTPするGUIアプリケーションXYZがあります。
このFTPに、以下のような現象が、数日から数週間毎にあります。
① ある時点でのFTPの失敗
1分周期で実行されるFTPが、ある時点で失敗する
② それ以降の連続失敗
一旦①が発生すると、端末再起動まで、それ以降FTPがずっと失敗し続ける
（XYZを再起動すれば復旧するかも知れないが、試せていない）
①②共、FTP失敗の際、try-catchで拾うExceptionのメッセージには、
「リモート サーバーに接続できません。」
とあります。
Windowsシステムイベントを確認すると、①が発生するより少し前のタイムスタンプで、
DNS Client Events（イベントID=1014）
「名前 xxxx の名前解決は、構成されたどの DNS サーバーからも応答がなく、タイムアウトしました。」
が必ずロギングされています。
※ xxxx は、本件で使用しているFTPサーバーとは異なります。
また、この現象は時々発生するが、xxxx はその都度様々です。
試したこと
DNS Client Events（イベントID=1014）の原因と対策をウェブで検索し、
a) ネットワークアダプタのプロパティからIPv6を無効化（チェックを外す）
b) レジストリのTcpip6-ParametersにDisabledComponentsを値0xffffffffで定義
c) ネットワークアダプタのプロパティからDNSを1.1.1.1、代替DNSを1.0.0.1に設定
d) FTPの接続先サーバーを名前でなくIPアドレスで指定
の4点をおこないましたが、状況が変わりません。
※ ipconfigすると、該当ネットワークアダプタにIPv6の表記が無いことから、IPv6は無効化されているようで、IPv6に起因しているのではないように思います。
補足
このXYZを、問題が発生している運用機の他に、2台の検証機に導入し、
検証機にも上記a)からd)の4点を適用して試験していますが、
検証機2台とも時々現象①は発生するものの、1分後の次のFTPは正常に送信されます。
つまり、運用機のみFTPが連続失敗します。
検証機1 : Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 10.0.19044
検証機2 : Windows 10 Pro 10.0.19042
検証機2台は社内にありますが、運用機は客先にあり、ネットワーク環境が異なり、
・インターネットプロバイダ
・接続先FTPサーバー
・ルータ
などは別になります。
素人の私見で、何らかの原因でネットワークアダプタに問題が起こり
（3台ともこの現象が発生するのでNICカード等、機器固有の問題ではないと思いますが）、
そのため何かのアプリケーションがDNSを使用しようとした際にイベントID=1014が発生し、
そのあおりを食う形でそれに続くFTPが失敗するのかと思いましたが、
なかなか苦しい説明です。
ちなみに、イベントID=1014が発生する前に何かその原因が無いかと、
その発生時刻の前の他の種類のイベントも見てみたのですが、
そういったロギングはされていないようでした。
質問

上記a)からd)までの対応をしてもなおイベントID=1014が発生しますが、どういった理由が考えられますでしょうか。

イベントID=1014が発生すると、FTPが失敗するのは、どういった理由が考えられますでしょうか。

イベントID=1014の発生を抑える方策はありますでしょうか。

検証機と運用機の現象の発現の仕方の違いの原因について、何が考えられますでしょうか。

イベントID=1014が発生した際でもFTPが失敗しないようにするには、或いは最低でも、上記2台の検証機のように、現象①が発生しても次の周期で復旧すれば良いのですが、そのようにする方策は何かありますでしょうか。


大変困っておりまして、質問の一部でも何かヒントになるような情報があればと思っています。
例えば、最悪の話、FTPが複数回失敗した時点でXYZを再起動する、などもやむを得ないのですが、そもそも、この現象が発生した際は端末再起動が必要ではないかとも思えます。
根本対策が難しい場合の離れ業の対応でも構いませんので、お知恵拝借できますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Event ID 1014: Microsoft Windows DNS Client に記されてる Method one, 及び three以降を試してみてはどうでしょう。(Method twoは既に試しているようなので)

ありがとうございます。
three, fourはすぐには難しいですが、とりあえずoneのみ社内検証機に適用してみようと思います。


検証機2台は社内にありますが、運用機は客先にあり、ネットワーク環境が異なり、
・インターネットプロバイダ
・接続先FTPサーバー
・ルータ
などは別になります。

インターネットプロバイダの中にはTCP接続回数に一定の上限を定めているところがあります。特に昨今のIPoE接続の場合、プロバイダ全体での接続数に上限があるため必然的に利用者毎にも制限が課せられます。対して従来のPPPoE接続ではそのような制限がないことも多いです。
その上で、FTPは古いプロトコルですので、通信毎やファイルの送受信毎にTCP接続を行います。１分ごとに接続しているとのことですので、この上限に抵触する可能性があります。また、「XYZ : C# GUIアプリケーション」の実装によってはより頻繁に接続切断を繰り返している可能性も考えられます。参考までに、よく使われているHTTPでは古くより接続を再利用する機能があるため、このような事態には陥りづらいです。
この現象はインターネットプロバイダ側からの制限なため、一度陥るとDNS名前解決のための接続も制限を受けます。インターネットプロバイダが提供するDNSサーバーであればこの制限に該当しない可能性もありますが、外部のDNSサーバーを利用するのであれば確実に該当します。つまりイベントID 1014は副次的なエラーの可能性があります。
まずはインターネットプロバイダへの接続にIPoEを使用しているかの確認と、インターネットプロバイダにTCP接続回数の制限があるか問い合わせてみることをお勧めします。

ありがとうございます。ただ、同じFTPサーバーを使う別の客先では、同じXYZを更に短い15秒周期でFTPをしているところもあり、頻度や回数の問題ではないかも知れないと思っています。

直接の解決策ではありませんが、調査の方向性だけ二つ示します。
Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 2019 特有のバグの可能性の再検証
検証はLTSC 2021(10.0.19044)で行っているようですが、問題が発生している環境のLTSC 2019(10.0.17763)から3年後のバージョンであり、カーネルレベルで多くのバグフィックスが行われていると考えられます。また、LTSC 2019はメインストリームサポートは既に終了しており、基本的にセキュリティ関連以外のバグは修正されませんが、LTSC 2021はまだメインストーリムであるため、現在もセキュリティ以外のバグが修正されています。そのため、LTSC 2021よりもLTSC 2019には多くの細かいバグが存在していると考えらます。
いわば、Windows Server 2016で発生する現象をWindows Server 2019で検証しているようなものです。極論を言えば、実施した検証はWindows 11で検証することとさほど変わりがないというと言う話です。
現在の検証結果だけで、OSに起因するバグではないと判断するのは時期尚早です。問題が発生する環境と同じOS(OSビルドのバージョンが同じであることはもちろんのこと、他の修正プログラムも同じ物が適用されていることが望ましい)で再度検証することを推奨します。
パケットキャプチャの実施
FTP通信のどこで失敗しているのかすらわからない状態のように見えます。サーバー側のログはもちろん確認してますよね？確認したけど、接続してきたというログがなかったということを前提で話をします。
ネットワーク通信がおかしいとき、どこがおかしいかわからないという場合は、PCのNICに対してパケットキャプチャを取得して分析してみるという方法があります。PCでWiresharkのようなソフトでパケット取得するのが一番簡単なのですが、PCにソフト入れられないという場合は、ポートミラーリング機能が付いたスイッチをかませて、他のPCで取得するという方法があります。これなら、運用環境に影響なく、調査が可能です。
パケットキャプチャをすれば、実際にDNSを引いているのか、その返答は正しく返ってきているのかがわかるため、ネットワーク環境が悪くてDNSがおかしいというのもわかります。また、他の制限で弾かれているというのであれば、送信パケットを送っても返事がないとか、そういうところで判断できます。そもそも、何もパケットを送らなくなったというのであれば、ネットワークではなくPC内部の問題の可能性が高いと推測できます。

私も数ヶ月前程前に、ある製品のFTPアップロード機能で、一定サイズ以上になると停止するという問題に頭を悩ましました。Windowsのファイアウォールを無効にすると現象が発生しなくなることはわかったのですが、OSのバグなのか製品のバグなのかサーバーが悪いのか全然わから無い状態でした。結局パケットキャプチャをした結果、Windowsファイウォールが有効だとデータ通信の最後の方のパケットを送らなくなり、サーバー側のタイムアウト(600秒)まで待つようになってしまっていたということでした。

ありがとうございます。デバッグの方法について、たいへん参考になりました。どうしても解決しなければ、客先に代替機を持っていき、当該機を引き取って検証してみる必要があると思います。ただ、実務上なかなか大変な部分もあります。
